# Display all process using a posix function

Tags: c, ubuntu, posix

I am trying to display currently running process in Ubuntu.

Right now I am using system() function to print running process in the terminal. Code:

```
system("ps -A");
```

This function displays all running process in the terminal.

But I want to this functionality using a POSIX function. I am not looking for a ready made code.

Can some one point me to the function name or any manual ?

Comment: 'system' by itself is a POSIX function call as declared in stdlib.h. Try running strace -ps to get an idea of what ps does.It mostly parses data from /proc/<pid>

Comment: +1 oh, I never knew about it. Anyways I am trying something different. I don't want direct output from "ps -A".

Comment: Oh, that looks scary : ), but I will definitely give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I want to this functionality using a POSIX function. I am not looking for a ready made code.

No POSIX function exists to list running processes. That is OS specific, not portable, rarely needed by applications and thus not part of POSIX.

But since you need this on Linux, the most POSIXy solution would be to use functions [`opendir()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir)/`readdir()`/`closedir()` to iterate over the content of `/proc` special file system.

All numeric entries in the directory are PIDs of running processes. Check the content the [`man 5 proc`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) for details what information about the running processes can be obtained from there. Then you can use the `open()`/`read()`/`close()` or [`readlink()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/readlink) calls to retrieve the information about a particular process from the `/proc/NNN/*` files.

On Linux, the standard tools like `ps` and `top` use the `/proc` to gather the information about processes. It is official Linux' interface to the information about running processes.

Answer (score 5):

`ps` is a POSIX command.

`popen` is a POSIX API for reading output from a command.

If you want a pure POSIX approach (maybe you want it portable to some OS that does not provide `/proc`), you should run `ps` with POSIX-only options and fetch the output from `popen`.

So, for example, maybe you want to call `popen("ps -A -o pid=", "r");` and then read through the list of PIDs.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know does `ps` on Linux internally loop over the directories (corresponding to process ids) found under `/proc`. So I think there is no single function doing that, you'd have to loop over the subdirectories of `/proc` yourself (using more generic POSIX functions such as `readdir` etc.).

Comment: How do I include proc in my program?

Comment: `/proc` should be a directory on your file system. You can get a list of its contents using the function `readdir` (see the `readdir` manpage by doing `man readdir` on a shell).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`popen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen)

Comment: Should I pass "ps -A" to pclose() and store the output into some array or buffer?

Comment: This question will answer you doubt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839232/popen-in-c