# Determine programmatically if a program is running

Tags: c, linux, process, pid

In C, how can I find out programmatically if a process is already running on Linux/Ubuntu to avoid having it start twice? I'm looking for something similar to pidof.

Comment: (You could perhaps create a temporary "lock" file in a known location when starting the program, then just check for existence of the file (and delete it on shutdown - although then you have a problem if the program terminates unexpectedly))

Comment: @marnir - that's why you have the program write its own PID to the file, then if the file exists, you can check to see if that PID is still active, and if so, if the process name matches your own. It isn't 100% foolproof, but still, abnormal terminations shouldn't be happening *that* often.

Comment: If the "lock file" contained the PID of the program, you could detect abnormal program termination in nearly all cases (is there a running process with the PID matching the PID file)?  This is not a perfect solution (finite number of PIDs, PID recycling).

Comment: @marnir - If you actually lock the lockfile, the lock will be released on process exit.  The program just tries for a non-blocking exclusive lock, and if it fails, someone else is running.

Comment: Anyone knows how to do this in Windows?

Comment: honestly, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460702/check-running-processes-in-c looks a clear, easy solution

Comment: @mtk Link is clean unless you know pid, which is the main issue of this topic.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can walk the `pid` entries in `/proc` and check for your process in either the `cmdline` file or perform a `readlink` on the `exe` link (The following uses the first method).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

pid_t proc_find(const char* name) 
{
    DIR* dir;
    struct dirent* ent;
    char* endptr;
    char buf[512];

    if (!(dir = opendir("/proc"))) {
        perror("can't open /proc");
        return -1;
    }

    while((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        /* if endptr is not a null character, the directory is not
         * entirely numeric, so ignore it */
        long lpid = strtol(ent->d_name, &endptr, 10);
        if (*endptr != '\0') {
            continue;
        }

        /* try to open the cmdline file */
        snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "/proc/%ld/cmdline", lpid);
        FILE* fp = fopen(buf, "r");

        if (fp) {
            if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp) != NULL) {
                /* check the first token in the file, the program name */
                char* first = strtok(buf, " ");
                if (!strcmp(first, name)) {
                    fclose(fp);
                    closedir(dir);
                    return (pid_t)lpid;
                }
            }
            fclose(fp);
        }

    }

    closedir(dir);
    return -1;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    if (argc == 1) {
        fprintf("usage: %s name1 name2 ...\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    int i;
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        pid_t pid = proc_find(argv[i]);
        if (pid == -1) {
            printf("%s: not found\n", argv[i]);
        } else {
            printf("%s: %d\n", argv[i], pid);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gave this a show - showing around 500ms to run this code each iteration why does this take so long? are there better ways to do this?

Comment: It depends on the number of processes you are running.

Comment: What about removing the filepath ahead of the program name?  Can you use comm instead of cmdline?  Also, how do you ignore killed processes?

Comment: Worked fine to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

This is the same as the code posted by John Ledbetter . It is good to refer to the file named stat in /proc/pid/ directory than cmdline since the former gives process states and process name. The cmdline file gives complete arguments with which the process is started. So that fails in some cases. Any way the idea given by John is good. Here I posted the modified code of John. I was looking for the code in c in Linux to check dhcp is running or not . With this code, I am able to do that. I hope it may be useful for someone like me.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include<unistd.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

pid_t proc_find(const char* name) 
{
    DIR* dir;
    struct dirent* ent;
    char buf[512];

    long  pid;
    char pname[100] = {0,};
    char state;
    FILE *fp=NULL; 

    if (!(dir = opendir("/proc"))) {
        perror("can't open /proc");
        return -1;
    }

    while((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        long lpid = atol(ent->d_name);
        if(lpid < 0)
            continue;
        snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "/proc/%ld/stat", lpid);
        fp = fopen(buf, "r");

        if (fp) {
            if ( (fscanf(fp, "%ld (%[^)]) %c", &pid, pname, &state)) != 3 ){
                printf("fscanf failed \n");
                fclose(fp);
                closedir(dir);
                return -1; 
            }
            if (!strcmp(pname, name)) {
                fclose(fp);
                closedir(dir);
                return (pid_t)lpid;
            }
            fclose(fp);
        }
    }


closedir(dir);
return -1;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    int i;
    if (argc == 1) {
        printf("usage: %s name1 name2 ...\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    for( i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        pid_t pid = proc_find(argv[i]);
        if (pid == -1) {
            printf("%s: not found\n", argv[i]);
        } else {
            printf("%s: %d\n", argv[i], pid);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On Android 5.1, the process name field in /proc/<PID>/stat has a pretty small character limit. Just a heads up that some OSs may experience this similar problem.

Answer (score 17):

There are ways to avoid `/proc` usage (and there might be good reasons to do so, e.g. `/proc` might not be installed at all, and/or it might have been symlinked to something deceptive, or that pid has been hidden in `/proc`). Granted, the below method doesn't look that good, I wish there were a proper API for that!

Anyway, section 1.9 of a 1997 [Unix programming FAQ](http://lib.ru/UNIXFAQ/unixprogrfaq.txt) says:

Use `kill()` with 0 for the signal number. There are four possible results from this call:

- `kill()` returns 0

  This implies that a process exists with the given PID, and the
        system would allow you to send signals to it. It is
        system-dependent whether the process could be a zombie.
- `kill()` returns -1, `errno` == `ESRCH`

  Either no process exists with the given PID, or security
        enhancements are causing the system to deny its existence. (On
        some systems, the process could be a zombie.)
- `kill()` returns -1, `errno` == `EPERM`

  The system would not allow you to kill the specified process.
        This means that either the process exists (again, it could be a
        zombie) or draconian security enhancements are present (e.g. your
        process is not allowed to send signals to *anybody*).
- `kill()` returns -1, with some other value of `errno`

  You are in trouble!

The most-used technique is to assume that success or failure with `EPERM`
implies that the process exists, and any other error implies that it
doesn't.

Comment: After re-reading your question... if all you want is preventing the process from being run twice, you could create a named kernel object (e.g. a semaphore, or shared memory) with an unique name and check for its existence in the beginning.  It might be better than a lock file as it will go away automatically if your process crashes.

Comment: But using proc you will have no disk I/O access.

Comment: Not all files necessitate disk access either.

Answer (score 3):

pidof works by walking over the [`/proc` filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs).  In C, you could do something similar by enumerating `/proc`; opening `/proc/X/cmdline` for every X where X is a list of one or more decimal numbers.  I don't know if you have any portability requirements but bear that in mind if you are to rely on the availability of `/proc`.

This problem is more commonly solved on UNIX-like systems by wrapping the start-up of the program and maintaining a PID file.  See `/etc/init.d/*` for classic examples of this approach.  You will need to be careful to ensure that the code which reads of writes the PID file does so in a safe manner (atomically).  If your target OS has a more capable init (such as [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd)), you may be able to out source this work to that.

Comment: A prime example of where Unix is "good enough" but hardly elegant.