# How to find if a process is running in C?

Tags: c, linux, process

I would like to find out if a process is running. I DO NOT want to use any system("") commands. Is there any C based function that lets you know if a process is running?

I would like to provide the process name and want to know if it's running.

Thanks,

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about what exactly you want to do. Do you know the pid or name of the process in question?

Comment: You might want to look at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667486/display-all-process-using-a-posix-function

Comment: Also see [Determine programmatically if a program is running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6898337/608639).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure, use [`kill(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html):

```
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <signal.h>

 int kill(pid_t pid, int sig);
```

> If sig is 0, then no signal is sent, but error checking is still performed; this can be used to check for  the  existence  of  a  process  ID  or process group ID.

So just call `kill(pid, 0)` on the process ID of the process that you want to check for and see if you get an error (`ESRCH`).

Comment: This is a good way to check if you have the process id, but he only has the process name.

Comment: @cegfault: That's true. A name doesn't really tell you "the process", though, since there may be many processes with the same name. I think the OP's question is lacking several important details.

Comment: There is no "process name" : `execve(argv[0], NULL, NULL);`

Comment: yeah, agreed. It's hard to give a good answer without more details

Comment: I was able to follow your approach with fetching the pid of my process. It really helped.

Comment: @Kitcha: great, I'm glad to hear :-)

Comment: @KerrekSBThis works well if I want to check the existence of a local process. But how can I check the process existence on another machine? I can rsh to that machine.

Comment: @werk: wow, that's a whole different question, and any answer will probably not be suitable for your problem. Yes, in principle you'd want to log into the machine somehow and then perform the local steps, but it sounds like you probably want some existing distributed job management system, rather than roll your own!

Comment: @KerrekSBThanks! This is what I thought. Meanwhile I will try Boost MPI.

Comment: And remember you have no way to know that pid's still refer to the same process they did a minute ago. It's one of the few serious design flaws in UNIX. Try to never ever use pid, asynchron signals or the library calls of system and select if you have any quality development in mind.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, another way to do this might include examining the contents of the `/proc` directory. Numbered directories are process IDs, while subdirectories containing the `cmdline` file show the name of the command.

For example, if `/proc/1234/cmdline` contains the value `foo`, then process `foo` has an ID of 1234. You could map names to PIDs this way, using standard file access functions in C. See [`proc(5)`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You may find this interesting: http://programming-in-linux.blogspot.com/2008/03/get-process-id-by-name-in-c.html

The "conventional and best way" to do this is read the `/proc` folder.  You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939778/linux-api-to-list-running-processes) for more, which references http://procps.sourceforge.net/, which may be of interest to you

Answer (score 0):

You can scan the `/proc` filesystem for all currently running processes, and see if the `cmdline` entry matches what you want for that particular process.

However, there is a race condition. The process may die after you have decided it was running.

The sure fire way to know if your process is still running is to be the one that launched the process. Then, when a child dies, you will get `SIGCHLD` and you can use `waitpid(-1,..)` to find out which child died.