# Python, what is the correct way to determine if a Unix process is running?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I have some existing code that determines whether the system is running:

```
    def is_running( self ):
        init_scripts = glob.glob( os.path.join( settings.INIT_SCRIPT_DIR, self.pp
ackage_name + '*' ) )
        running = False

        if len( init_scripts ) > 0:
            running = True
            for init_script in init_scripts:
                process = subprocess.Popen( [ 'sudo', init_script, 'status' ] )
                process.wait()
                if process.returncode != 0:
                    running = False
                    break

        return running
```

I'm seeing that process.returncode is non zero, even though the required daemons are running.  What is the best way to check from Python that certain daemons are running?

Answer (score 0):

You may find this answer useful:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3667838/2431268

There are no POSIX calls to do this and there is also no way to do this through the python standard library.