# Minix: Determining size of process table

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, system-calls

I would like to iterate through all possible process id's but for this, I would need to know the limit of the process table. How can I find this out?

My idea is to do something like

```
    while (counter < table size)
{
    do something
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should be specific and your relevant code should be [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no posix API to get these info directly in C,you need popen() function to call command line to get this kind of info,I do not recommend system() though it is similar with popen.([Display all process using a posix function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667486/display-all-process-using-a-posix-function)).

the system max process number can be set/check by command ulimit.

```
popen("ulimit -a max user processes","r");
```

or you can check the current max number in current processes ids.(ps aux show all processes,sed find last line ,and awk find process id)

```
FILE *fp = popen("ps aux|sed -n '$p'|awk '{print $2F}'","r");
if(NULL!=fp)
{
    char buff[1024];
    fgets(buff,1024,fp);
    printf("%s\n",buff);
    pclose(fp);
}
```