# Get (effective) user ID given a PID in C

Tags: c, posix, pid

Given a process's PID, how can I find the process owner/group **from C**? (like [getuid](https://linux.die.net/man/2/geteuid), just for a given PID)

On the internet, there are a lot of answers that suggest using "ps", but I am looking for a (preferably POSIX-compliant) native solution, e.g. a system call.

Comment: Does parsing `/proc/PID/status` work for you? That's what my `ps` does.

Comment: `getpwuid()` should do it.

Comment: Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3668051/315052), `ps` is a POSIX command, and `popen` is a POSIX API, so a POSIX-compliant solution is to parse `ps` output invoked by `popen`.

Comment: @jxh He  explicitly does *not* want to use `ps` , but use the posix api directly...

Comment: @GriffithLea `getwuid` gets you the password entry for a given uid. But he wants to get the uid of the owner for a pid.

Comment: Oh, good grief - thanks, Michael. I guess I need new glasses.

Comment: And I don't think that the posix API provides for this functionality. Since it seems that `ps` itself uses the proc file system to retrieve the uid of an arbitrary process, I guess facilitating linux specific stuff like the proc or sys file system would be the only way to go, as @CupcakeProtocol already suggested?

Comment: @jxh The output of `ps` varies considerably from one POSIX compliant platform to the next.

Comment: @MichaelBeer: That's assuming a linux compatible system. In theory, for a pure POSIX system, parsing `ps` is "portable".

Comment: @jxh thats right. I don&#39;t think that there is a native *and* portable solution to this (alas, it all depends what the OT means by 'native').

Comment: @jojonas what exactly do you mean by 'native'? I don't think the posix c API provides for this (by the way, the posix functions aren't system calls in general ...)

Comment: @tadman: Yes, but the `ps` for POSIX documents minimal functionality, which includes being able to emit the effective user id via a custom `ps` output format string.

Comment: @jxh A good point, didn't think about that.